# Hyperlinks not working in IE8 with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, href, alert

I've looked all over the place for an fix for this but I can't seem to find it!

I've made my own old browser alert using Twitter Bootstrap's alert class with a black overlay on the content under the alert, it looks great, but I want a hyperlink in the alert that takes the user off to http://browsehappy.com/ where they can then update their browser. But the hyperlink doesn't do anything in IE - it works in everything else (even IE7!) but in IE8 it just shows up blue and isn't clickable.

I've made a JSFiddle with conditional comments in it so you can see what I'm doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/X3tKs/2/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="black" style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:black;opacity:0.8;filter:alpha(opacity=80);position:absolute;top:52px;z-index:3000;"></div>
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    Yikes! You're using an old browser! This page might not work the way it should. <a href="http://browsehappy.com" target="_blank">Time to update!</a>
</div>
```

Any help will be MUCH appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
Turns out it was just my fault for using an online browser simulator! Thank you @joshhunt for your comment regarding this - I sent the link to my friend who has a windows computer and they confirmed it was working, it was actually Browserstack that wasn't working right. I tried taking everything out - bootstrap styling, black div (thanks @OJay) and it still didn't work, so I figured it couldn't have been my code. Time to invest in an old Windows laptop for testing! :)

Comment: try a js solution, do want to use jQuery?

Comment: I'm willing to try anything to make it work! What do you suggest?

Comment: The JS Fiddle (http://fiddle.jshell.net/X3tKs/2/show/) seems to be working fine for me in both Windows XP IE8 and Windows 7 IE8.

Comment: Turns out it was just my fault for using an online browser simulator! Thank you @joshhunt for your comment regarding this - I sent the link to my friend who has a windows computer and they confirmed it was working, it was actually Browserstack that wasn't working right. I tried taking everything out - bootstrap styling, black div (thanks @OJay) and it still didn't work, so I figured it couldn't have been my code. Time to invest in an old Windows laptop for testing! :)

Comment: Yeah, IE emulators are notoriously inaccurate; see e.g. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13422

Comment: That's strange because I was also using Browserstack... As far as I'm aware Browserstack doesn't use emulators for IE but just loads a virtual machine with the actual version of IE on it.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    Yikes! You're using an old browser! This page might not work the way it should. <a href="http://browsehappy.com" id="update_link" target="_blank">Time to update!</a>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$("#update_link").click(function(){
    var url = "http://browsehappy.com";
    window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

### CSS

```
#update_link{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```